# Connection on Submanifold using given connection on ambient manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

This result features in Hicks' Notes on Differential Geometry book.The theorem states that given $C^\infty$ fields X and Y on a submanifold M, we have $$\bar D_X Y=D_X Y+V(X,Y)$$ where $\bar D$ is a Riemannian Connection on the ambient manifold $\bar M$, $D$ being the Riemannian Connection on M and V being a symmetric vector values $(0,2)\;C^\infty$ tensor.
I dont understand how that decomposition into tangential and normal components is brought about??I know that every vector can be written as sum of tangential and normal components but not sure how to relate that here.

Now in the proof , we employ Gram-Schimdt orthogonalisation process to obtain orthonormal vector fields $ W_1,\ldots,W_n$ on $\bar U$ such that $W_1|_U,\ldots,W_k|_U$ are orthonormal base for $M_m ,m\in U$, while $W_{k+1}|_U,\ldots,W_{n}|_U$ give $\bar M$-vector fields on $U$ which give a base for the orthogonal complement to $M_m$.I do not understand the last part of this argument with regards to the complement.Finally I let 
$\bar D_{W_i}W_j=\sum_{r=1}^{n}B_{ij}^{r}$ on $\bar U$. Then
$$\bar D_X Y =\sum(XY_j)W_j+\sum Y_jB_{ji}^{r}W_r$$

Can someone explain what the $B_{ij}^{r}$ are , though they look like Christoffel symbols to me. The book concludes this as the result.But I am unable to do the same. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think the easiest way to see that $\overline D_XY$ equals the tangential component of $D_XY$, denoted $D_XY^T$, is to observe that $X,Y \mapsto D_XY^T$ defines a metric, torsionfree connection on $N$

Comment: Thank you for the response.But can you elaborate??Are you talking about the mapping??

Comment: I confused $\overline D$ and $D$ in my first comment: Let $\overline D$ be the ambient manifold's connection and $D$ the submanifold's. If you can show that for vectorfieds $X,Y$ of $M$ the map $X,Y \mapsto \overline D_XY^T$ defines a metric and torsionfree connection on $M$ by unqueness of the riemannian connection of $M$ it follows $D_XY = \overline D_XY^T$. So you need to proof $Xg(Y,Z) = g(\overline D_XY^T,Z) + g(X,\overline D_YZ^T)$ and $[X,Y] = \overline D_XY^T - \overline D_YX^T$ for vectorfields $X,Y,Z$ that are tangential to $M$. Also this should be found in most textbooks

Comment: Thanks and what about the second term. How do I conclude that it is  the normal component??Also my problem is that once thisdecomposition is given, the verification maybe be done.But how is that decomposition motivated in the first place??

Answer (score 0):

The important ingredient here is the following generally statement true for any manifold $M$ with a linear connection $\nabla$: if $p \in M$ and $U, V, U', V'$ are vector fields with $U'_p = U_p = u$ and $V'_p = V_p = v$ then $(\nabla _U V)_p = (\nabla _{U'} V')_p$.

Let $X, Y \in \mathcal X (M)$ and let $\bar X, \bar Y \in \mathcal X (\bar M)$ be two extensions of $X,Y$ from $M$ to $\bar M$ (i.e. $\bar X \Big| _M = X$ and $\bar Y \Big| _M = Y$). For $p \in M \subset \bar M$, it makes then sense to consider $(\bar D _{\bar X} \bar Y) _p \in T_p \bar M$. Notice that $T_p M$ lives inside $T_p \bar M$, where it has an orthogonal complement. Decompose, then, $(\bar D _{\bar X} \bar Y) _p$ into a projection onto $T_p M$ and a part orthogonal to $T_p M$. Call the projection $(D _X Y) _p$, and the orthogonal part $V(X,Y) _p$. Notice that since $T_p \bar M = T_p M \oplus T_p ^\perp M$ is a direct sum, the above decomposition is unique.

The problem is to show that $(D _X Y) _p$ and $V(X,Y) _p$ do not depend on the extensions $\bar X, \bar Y$ used. Let then $\bar X '$ and $\bar Y '$ be two other extensions of $X$ and $Y$. Using the general statement at the beginning of this post, one obtains that $(\bar D _{\bar X '} \bar Y ') _p = (\bar D _{\bar X} \bar Y) _p$ for every $p \in M$, hence $D$ and $V$ are well defined (i.e. they do not depend on the extensions used).

One then shows that $D$ is a torsion-free linear connection compatible with the Riemann structure on $M$, and that $V$ is symmetric and $\mathcal C ^\infty (M)$-bilinear.

The symmetry of $V$, for instance, follows from the fact that $D$ and $\bar D$ are torsionless and from the general fact that $[X, Y] _p = [X_p, Y_p]$: pick two extensions $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ and then for every $p \in M$

$$V(X,Y) _p = (\bar D _{\bar X} \bar Y)_p - (D _X Y)_p = \Big( (\bar D _{\bar Y} \bar X)_p + [\bar X, \bar Y]_p \Big) - \Big( (D _Y X)_p + [X,Y]_p \Big) = \\
\Big( (\bar D _{\bar Y} \bar X)_p - (D _Y X)_p \Big) + \Big( [\bar X, \bar Y]_p - [X, Y]_p \Big) = \\
V(Y,X)_p + \Big( [\bar X _p, \bar Y _p] - [X _p, Y _p] \Big) = V(Y,X)_p$$

because $\bar X _p = X _p$ and $\bar Y _p = Y _p$.

To show that $D$ is torsionless, use the fact that if $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ extend $X$ and $Y$, then $[\bar X, \bar Y]$ extends $[X, Y]$: for any $Z \in \mathcal X (M)$

$$\langle D _X Y - D _Y X - [X, Y], Z \rangle _M = \langle D _X Y - D _Y X - [X, Y], Z \rangle _{\bar M} = \\
\left< \Big( \bar D _{\bar X} \bar Y - V(X,Y) \Big) - \Big( \bar D _{\bar Y} \bar X - V(Y,X) \Big) - [\bar X, \bar Y], Z \right> _{\bar M} = \\
\left< \underbrace { \Big( \bar D _{\bar X} \bar Y - \bar D _{\bar Y} \bar X - [\bar X, \bar Y] \Big) } _{= 0} - \Big( V(X,Y) - V(Y,X) \Big) , Z \right> _{\bar M} = \\
- \left< \Big( V(X,Y) - V(Y,X) \Big) , Z \right> _{\bar M} = 0 ,$$

where the underbraced expression is precisely the torsion of $\bar D$, so it is $0$ (because $\bar D$ is the Levi-Civita connection on $\bar M$), and the last scalar product is again $0$ because the vector field on the right position lives in $T^\perp M$ while $Z$ lives in $TM$, so they are orthogonal. Since the Riemann metric on $M$ is non-degenerate and $\langle D _X Y - D _Y X - [X, Y], Z \rangle _M = 0$ for all $Z \in \mathcal X (M)$, it follows that $D _X Y - D _Y X - [X, Y] = 0$ and the left-hand side is exactly the torsion of $D$.

All the important properties of $D$ are proved like this: you extend the fields to $\bar M$, and there you use the corresponding properties of $\bar D$ and the fact that all the intervening objects do not depend on the chosen extensions.